# Why does Proto-Indo-Aryan *ẓ seem to have different outcomes despite sharing the same phonological context?

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, sanskrit, declension

It is well known that Proto-Indo-Aryan **s* had an allophone **z* in voiced contexts. Due to some phonetic changes (i.e. RUKI law and the shift **śt* > *ṣṭ*), they both could undergo retroflexion, thus producing two new allophones **ṣ*, **ẓ*. My question concerns the reflexes of the latter allophone in Sanskrit. It seems that the reflexes of **ẓ* have a somewhat strange distribution.

Most grammars of Sanskrit agree that this **ẓ* was eliminated from the phonetic inventory of the language in several ways depending on the contest:
(1) In internal sandhi, it either was completely lost when it occurred before a consonant of the dental or retroflex series with compensatory lengthening of the preceding vowel, as in नीड *nīḍá-* < **niẓḍá-* 'nest' (cf. OHG *nest*, Lith. *lìzdas*, OArm. նիստ *nist*, OCS гнѣздо *gnězdo*), or it was substituted by *ḍ* before other kinds of consonants, as in विप्रुड्भ्यः *vipruḍ-bhyáḥ* < **vipruẓ-bhyas* dat./abl. pl. of विप्रुट् *vipruṭ* 'drop'.
(2) In external sandhi, *-iḥ*, *-uḥ* (< **-iṣ*, **-uṣ*) are substituted with *-r* if they are followed by a vowel or a voiced consonant, e.g. अग्निरस्ति *agnir asti* < *agniḥ + asti* 'there is fire', or in the compound यजुर्वेद​ *yajur-veda* < *yajuḥ + veda* 'the Veda of the (sacrificial) formulas'. This sandhi rule can also be explained through a similar change where **ṣ* > **ẓ* / __[+ voiced], and at a later stage **ẓ* > *r*.

If this account is correct, then in theory we should only find *ḍ* before inflectional suffixes beginning in voiced consonants, e.g. *-bhiḥ* instrumental, *-bhyaḥ*, *-bhyām* dative and ablative plural and dual, because as far as I know, when declining a noun, only internal sandhi applies. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. As a matter of fact, besides nouns like विप्रुष् *vipruṣ-* 'drop', द्विष् *dviṣ-* 'enemy', which indeed do have *ḍ* in their declension (let's call them Set A), there are also a few *s*-stems, e.g. हविस् *havis-* 'oblation', यजुस् *yájus-* 'sacrificial formula' and of the like, which have for example हविर्भिः *havir-bhiḥ* and यजुर्भिः *yájur-bhiḥ* (let's call them Set B), almost as if an external sandhi would apply here.

It seems to me that there is no relevant difference between nouns of Set A and B, at least from a phonological standpoint. More specifically, their phonological context is the same, i.e. an original PIE **s* is retroflexed to **ṣ* (because it is placed after *i* or *u*), which then turns into **ẓ* whenever followed by a voiced consonant. Yet, they appear to show different reflexes of **ẓ*, mainly *ḍ* for Set A and *r* for Set B. How is this possible? Can this apparent incongruence be phonologically motivated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differentiation is not derivable from synchronic phonetic context, it comes from the root vs. suffix distinction, where root-final *s,ṣ* dissimilate to *t,ṭ*, for example *vas* 'dwell' → (future) vat-syāmi; *ghas* 'eat' → (desiderative) *ji-ghat-sa*. We find examples like *mās* 'moon' → *mādbhis*. The divergent treatment of *s* in the ruki environment, *ṣ* → *ṭ* vs *ẓ*, is parallel. While dissimilation itself is phonetically explicable, a purely phonetic mechanism does not explain why suffixal and root sibilants are treated differently.

[Kobayashi (2004, §42)](http://gengo.l.u-tokyo.ac.jp/masatok/hpiac_2004.pdf) has some discussion of dissimilation which tries to make the process be somewhat less irregular, but ultimately has to appeal to on-phonetic concepts of restructuring and the "obscuring" of roots (simplifying *ss* to *s* makes it hard to parse the root). A possible path for unifying the contexts *s* and stop after a sibilant is a presumed syllabification restriction that *sbh* etc is not a possible onset cluster: but again, that does not explain the root vs. suffix divergence.

Comment: This is interesting. I had the intuition that it all came down to the fact that Set A nouns are root stems while Set B nouns have suffixal element in -s-, but I wasn't quite sure. Your answer has been very helpful. Thank you.